# Optimize querying 100 million records- Postgres - indexes

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, postgresql-performance

Currently our queries are not performant.

**Table: (Item)** 100 million rows.

```
id: uuid
user_id: bigInt
item_type_id: uuid
status: varchar
start: date
end: date
```

Index on `user_id, item_type_id`

Query:

```
select * from items 
where ( 
    start <= query.endDate
    and  ( end is null or end >= query.startDate ) 
    and item_type_id in query.item_type_ids 
)
```

We know 90 percentage of the time the query date range is current month.

Comment: I see thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. Why can't we have index on end date that has null value? Date range sounds alike a good idea.

Comment: It's not that you can't have an index on `null` end date, it's the fact that the null requires an `OR` condition which is known to be hard to optimize. By not having NULLs you can get rid of the OR.

Comment: If you are still interested, this can probably be optimized further. Disclose the typical selectivity of each filter, the percentage of rows in the "current month" - plus an *exact* definition of the subset of rows that cover "90 percent" of all queries ("current month" is fuzzy). Provide the exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), your version of Postgres, and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for a typical query. And describe the general workload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR conditions are typically very hard to optimize (not only for Postgres). One way to get rid of that is to store `infinity` instead of `NULL` for the end date to indicate "no end date".

Then your query can be simplified to:

```
select * 
from items 
where start <= query.endDate
  and end >= query.startDate
  and item_type_id in query.item_type_ids
```

If you don't want to (or can't) update all rows where `end` is null, another option is to create an index with a date range:

```
create index on items (daterange("start", "end", '[]'));
```

The range is inclusive for both values. A `null` value will be treated as infinity by date range.

Then change your query to use:

```
select * 
from items 
where daterange("start", "end", '[]') @> daterange(query.startDate, query.endDate, '[]')
  and item_type_id in query.item_type_ids
```

Comment: Thanks horse_with_no_name. Also do you think the item_type_id in query.item_type_ids  is efficient, since its where-in query, what get rid of that and filter in memory

Comment: @trenatoid: that depends on how much this will reduce the number of rows.